Connecting to CloudSQL through cloud-sql-proxy running on a bastion vm
I'm working on a more secure iteration of GCP project setup where there is a bastion host, and the cloudsql instance doesn't have a public IP.
In the current setup cloud-sql-proxy is being used locally to get to CloudSQL instances. But in the new iteration I've got terraform starting cloud-sql-proxy on the bastion vm;
module "bastion-host" {
  source  = "terraform-google-modules/bastion-host/google"
  version = "6.0.0"

  project = var.project
  zone    = var.zone
  network = var.network
  subnet  = var.subnet
  members = var.members
  
  additional_ports = [
    "22",
    "3306",
  ]

  startup_script = <<EOT
    #!/bin/bash
    sudo apt-get update
    $(gcloud info --format="value(basic.python_location)") -m pip install numpy
    URL="https://storage.googleapis.com/cloud-sql-connectors/cloud-sql-proxy/v2.6.1"
    curl "$URL/cloud-sql-proxy.linux.amd64" -o cloud-sql-proxy
    chmod +x cloud-sql-proxy
    ./cloud-sql-proxy --private-ip ${var.project}:${var.db_instance_region}:${var.db_instance_name}
  EOT
  
}

resource "google_project_iam_member" "bastion" {
  for_each = toset(["roles/editor"])
  project  = var.project
  role     = each.value
  member   = "serviceAccount:${module.bastion-host.service_account}"
}

The firewall is configured to allow ports 22 & 3306 for the IAP IP range (35.235.240.0/20). I've verified that cloud-sql-proxy is running on 3306 and ran another instance on another port and connected it to the database instance.
From my machine I can open an SSH tunnel to the bastion vm, but I can't bind port 3306 on there to my machine in order to access the database through that machine. I've found a few things written about this general topic, but nothing that combines the bastion host running cloud-sql-proxy itself for people to route traffic through.
What I want to do is use IAP to bind a local port to 3306 on the bastion vm where cloud-sql-proxy is running, but I get the following;
❯ gcloud compute start-iap-tunnel bastion-vm 3306 --local-host-port=localhost:3310 --zone=europe-west2-a --project=my-project

Testing if tunnel connection works.
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.start-iap-tunnel) While checking if a connection can be made: Error while connecting [4003: 'failed to connect to backend']. (Failed to connect to port 3306)

I can however get an SSH connection to the vm and run cloud-sql-proxy manually;
❯ gcloud compute ssh --zone europe-west2-a bastion-vm --tunnel-through-iap --project my-project

Linux bastion-vm 5.10.0-28-cloud-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 5.10.209-2 (2024-01-31) x86_64

The programs included with the Debian GNU/Linux system are free software;
the exact distribution terms for each program are described in the
individual files in /usr/share/doc/*/copyright.

Debian GNU/Linux comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY, to the extent
permitted by applicable law.
Last login: Tue Apr  9 09:45:12 2024 from 35.225.242.4
mwalker@bastion-vm:~$ cloud-sql-proxy --private-ip my-project:europe-west2:my-project-8-b7d9f5df
2024/04/09 12:36:07 Authorizing with Application Default Credentials
2024/04/09 12:36:07 [my-project:europe-west2:my-project-8-b7d9f5df] Listening on 127.0.0.1:3307
2024/04/09 12:36:07 The proxy has started successfully and is ready for new connections!

I've also got tinyproxy running on the vm and I can get visibility of kubernetes though that which is the other part of the puzzle of putting everything behind private IPs.
❯ gcloud compute ssh bastion-vm \
    --tunnel-through-iap \
    --project=alldam-production \
    --zone=europe-west2-a \
    --ssh-flag="-4 -L8888:localhost:8888 -N -q -f"

❯ export HTTPS_PROXY=localhost:8888
kubectl get ns
NAME              STATUS   AGE
default           Active   13d
kube-node-lease   Active   13d
kube-public       Active   13d
kube-system       Active   13d


Are you sure that it is more secure to not have public IP?

@guillaumeblaquiere well, the assumption being that if it has a public IP, anybody can locate the instance. If it doens't, you need to be allowed in.

I don't know how the startup script interacts with long running processes. Have you tried running the Proxy as either a background process or with Tmux? Also, even though the page is for AlloyDB, there are some good options here: https://cloud.google.com/alloydb/docs/connect-external

@enocom Solved this one today! cloud-sql-proxy was listening to localhost, and needed binding to 0.0.0.0!

Bigquery has a public IP and nobody want to remove it! In addition, on Cloud SQL, if you have a public IP, but no authorized network, nothing will be located because you will always received a 403 whatever the network you use over the world! Removing public IP from Cloud SQL database comes from a old world assumption.

@guillaumeblaquiere Yeah I get that, but it's also one of the things that SCC flags as an issue. I think the concern with the authorized networks approach is that it adds restrictions to developers who maybe work from different places or who don't have a static IP.

I personally allow public IP on Cloud SQL, and activate the org policy to set authorized network. The main issue in the public IP feature, is the authorized network, you have to block it! The developers must use Cloud SQL proxy to connect the database. It works from any place in the world!

This turned out to be a classic case of missing the simple/obvious.
The startup script was launching cloud-sql-proxy with the default parameters;
./cloud-sql-proxy --private-ip ${var.project}:${var.db_instance_region}:${var.db_instance_name}

This meant that it was listening out on localhost:3306.
Updating this to bind to all network interfaces means I can then connect to it from my local machine.
./cloud-sql-proxy --private-ip --address 0.0.0.0 --port 3306 ${var.project}:${var.db_instance_region}:${var.db_instance_name}

And port added so that it's explicit.
